# Can't pass angular-youtube-embed player to factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube

I'm using https://github.com/brandly/angular-youtube-embed.

Accessing the player (from docs):

[image]

My code (also see [GitHub](https://github.com/adamzerner/skimmable-videos/tree/playerFactory/client)):

**form.html**

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <youtube-video 
    video-url='formCtrl.skim.url'
    player='formCtrl.player'
    class='embed-responsive-item'>
  </youtube-video>
</div>
```

**player.factory.js**

```
angular.module('skimmableVideosApp')
  .factory('Player', function () {
    return {
      player: {}
    };
  });
```

**form.controller.js**

```
...
this.player = Player.player;
...
```

**setbox.directive.js**

```
function SetboxCtrl(Player) {
  this.set = function() {
    console.log(Player.player);
  };
}
```

The `player` is shared between a couple of nested directives. It seems cleaner to me to put the player in a factory to be passed around, rather than passing it between the nested directives using isolate scope. And so that's what I'm trying to do. (Note: passing it between the nested directives using isolate scope does work, I tested it.)

When I click a button, it runs that `set` function above, and it logs out `{}`. Meaning that `Player.player` isn't getting updated to what I want it to be. Why is this?

Edit: When I do `Player.player = this.player;` instead of `this.player = Player.player;` in `form.controller.js`, the `set()` function logs `undefined`. Which makes me think that the player is being set after the form controller runs.

[image]

[image]

I'm also getting an `undefined is not a function` error, as seen in the screenshots and don't know why.

Comment: The `undefined` isnot a function error, we cant guess because code is less. but why the `Player.player` is empty object is because, you've not set the object anywhere. In the service also it's empty

Comment: @mohamedrias it seems that `this.player` is set by the library to the actual player object. My thinking is that before the library sets `this.player`, I'd set it to `Player.player`. That way, when the library sets it, it'll update `Player.player` via reference.